# Angular 1.5.x/Jasmine - Expected spy to have been called but it was never called

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-components, angularjs

POST-EDIT: I've just solved the issue, though maybe someone has a better solution. I'll post my solution soon, but if someone has a correct solution I'll accept their answer.

I'm migrating my application from 1.4 to 1.5 and changing all my controllers and directives to components. I now have a test that once worked not working and I'd like some guidance.

I'm trying to spy on a service method and according to the unit test it's not calling. This is not the case as an API call is made when the application is run. Here is the message I receive:

[image]

This is my component file:

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    angular.module("app").component("profileComponent", {
        templateUrl: "/templates/profile.component.html",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        bindings: {
            resolvedUser: "<"
        },
        controller: function(ImageService, $state){
            const vm = this;
            const resolvedUser = this.resolvedUser;

            resolvedUser ? vm.user = resolvedUser : $state.go("404");

            vm.$onInit = function(){
                ImageService.findByName(vm.user.pokemon.name)
                    .then(function(res){
                        vm.user.pokemon.id = res.id;
                        vm.user.pokemon.image = res.sprites.front_default;
                        vm.user.pokemon.type = res.types[0].type.name;
                    })
                    .catch(function(res){
                        vm.user.pokemon.image = "https://www.native-instruments.com/forum/data/avatars/m/328/328352.jpg?1439377390";
                    });
            }

        }
    });
})();
```

And here is the relevant parts from my spec file. I've made a comment where the test is failing:

```
describe("profile.component", function(){
    var profileComponent, ImageService, $q, $httpBackend, $state, resolvedUser, jazzSpy, IS,
        API = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";

    var RESPONSE_SUCCESS = // very large variable I've omitted for brevity.

beforeEach(angular.mock.module("app"));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("ui.router"));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_ImageService_, _$q_, _$httpBackend_, _$state_, _$rootScope_){
        ImageService = _ImageService_;
        $q = _$q_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $state = _$state_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $rootScope.$new();
    }));

    describe("profileComponent with a valid user and valid Pokemon", function(){

        beforeEach(inject(function(_$componentController_){
            singleUser = { id: 2, name: "Erlich Bachman", email: "erlich@aviato.com", phone: 4155552233, pokemon: { isPresent: true, name: "celebi"}, icon: { isPresent: false, name: null} };
            let bindings = {resolvedUser: singleUser, ImageService: ImageService, $state: $state };
            profileComponent = _$componentController_("profileComponent", { $scope: {} }, bindings);
            profileComponent.$onInit();
        }));

            beforeEach(function(){
                spyOn(ImageService, "findByName").and.callThrough();
            });

            it("should set state to resolvedUser", function(){
                expect(profileComponent.user).toEqual(singleUser);
            });

            it("should expect ImageService to be defined", function(){
                expect(ImageService.findByName).toBeDefined();
            });

            it("should call ImageService.findByName() and return Pokemon icon", function(){

                  expect(profileComponent.user.pokemon.name).toEqual("celebi");

                $httpBackend.whenGET(API + "celebi").respond(200, $q.when(RESPONSE_SUCCESS));
                $httpBackend.flush();

                // This is where the test fails
                  expect(ImageService.findByName).toHaveBeenCalledWith("celebi");
            });
        });
```

Comment: You've got race condition. $onInit is called before spyOn.

Comment: And you got the right answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned before, $onInit needs to be called after spyOn:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    spyOn(ImageService, "findByName").and.callThrough();
    profileComponent.$onInit();
});
```